# Phonegap download mp3 file

Tags: android, cordova, download

I am building a android applikation using Phonagap and jquery mobile.

In the app I need to download some mp3-files, but it won't work

Here is my function:

```
function downloadFile() {

var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://media.domain.com/myfile.mp3");
var filepath = remoteFile.substring(remoteFile.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    filePath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    }
);



}
```

What am I doing wrong..?

Comment: perhaps you want to try http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/de.fastr.phonegap.plugins.downloader

Answer (score 0):

remoteFile does not appear to be set.